# Combining every column-combination of an arbitrary number of matrices

Tags: for-loop, iterator, combinations, julia

I'm trying to figure out a way to do a certain "reduction"
I have a **varying** number of matrices of **varying** size, e.g

```
1 2 2 2 5 6...70 70
3 7 8 9 7 7...88 89

1 3 4
2 7 7
3 8 8
9 9 9

.
.

44 49 49 49 49 49 49
50 50 50 50 50 50 50
87 87 88 89 90 91 92
```

What I need to do (and I hope that I'm explaining this clearly enough) is to combine **any possible
combination of columns** from these matrices, this means that one column might be

```
1
3
1
2
3
9

.
.
.

44
50
87
```

Which would reduce down to

```
1
2
3
9
.
.
.
44
50
87
```

The reason why I'm doing this is because I need to find the smallest unique combined column

*What am I trying to accomplish*

For those interested, I'm trying to find the smallest set of gene knockouts
to disable reactions. Here, every matrix represents a reactions, and the columns represent the indices of 
the genes that would disable that reaction.

The method may be as *brute force* as needed, as these matrices rarely become overwhelmingly large, 
and the reaction combinations won't be long either

**The problem**

I can't (as far as I know) create a for loop with an arbitrary number of  iterators, and the number of 
matrices (reactions to disable) is arbitrary.

**Clarification**

If I have matrices A,B,C with columns a1,a2...b1,b2...c1...cn what I need
are the columns [a1 b1 c1], [a1, b1, c2], ..., [a1 b1 cn] ... [an bn cn]

**Solution**
Courtesy of [Michael Ohlrogge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084240/4551168) below.

Extension of his answer, for completeness

His solution ends with

```
MyProd = product(Array_of_ColGroups...)
```

Which gets the job done

And picking up where he left off

```
collection = collect(MyProd); #MyProd is an iterator
merged_cols = Array[] # the rows of 'collection' are arrays of arrays

for (i,v) in enumerate(collection)
    # I apologize for this line
    push!(merged_cols, sort!(unique(vcat(v...)))) 
end

# find all lengths so I can find which is the minimum
lengths = map(x -> length(x), merged_cols);

loc_of_shortest = find(broadcast((x,y) -> length(x) == y, merged_cols,minimum(lengths)))

best_gene_combos = merged_cols[loc_of_shortest]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** - complete solution:

```
# example matrices
a = rand(1:50, 8,4); b = rand(1:50, 10,5); c = rand(1:50, 12,4);
Matrices = [a,b,c];

toJagged(x) = [x[:,i] for i in 1:size(x,2)];
JaggedMatrices = [toJagged(x) for x in Matrices];

Combined = [unique(i) for i in JaggedMatrices[1]];
for n in 2:length(JaggedMatrices)
  Combined = [unique([i;j]) for i in Combined, j in JaggedMatrices[n]];
end

Lengths         = [length(s) for s in Combined];
Minima          = findin(Lengths, min(Lengths...));
SubscriptsArray = ind2sub(size(Lengths), Minima);
ComboTuples     = [((i[j] for i in SubscriptsArray)...) for j in 1:length(Minima)]
```

**Explanation**:

Assume you have matrix `a` and `b`

```
a = rand(1:50, 8,4);
b = rand(1:50, 10,5);
```

Express them as a jagged array, columns first

```
A = [a[:,i] for i in 1:size(a,2)];
B = [b[:,i] for i in 1:size(b,2)];
```

Concatenate rows for all column combinations using a list comprehension; remove duplicates on the spot:

```
Combined = [unique([i;j]) for i in A, j in B];
```

You now have all column combinations of a and b, as concatenated rows with duplicates removed. Find the lengths easily:

```
Lengths = [length(s) for s in Combined];
```

If you have more than two matrices, perform this process iteratively in a for loop, e.g. by using the `Combined` matrix in place of `a`. e.g. if you have a matrix `c`:

```
c = rand(1:50, 12,4);
C = [c[:,i] for i in 1:size(c,2)];
Combined = [unique([i;j]) for i in Combined, j in C];
```

Once you have the Lengths array as a multidimensional array (as many dimensions as input matrices, where the size of each dimension is the number of columns in each matrix), you can find the column combinations that correspond to the lowest value (there may well be more than one combination), via a simple `ind2sub` operation:

```
Minima = findin(Lengths, min(Lengths...));
SubscriptsArray = ind2sub(size(Lengths), Minima)
```

(e.g. for a randomized run with 3 input matrices, I happened to get 4 results with the minimal length of 19. The result of ind2sub was `([4,4,3,4,4],[3,3,4,5,3],[1,3,3,3,4])`

You can convert this further to a list of "Column Combination" tuples with a (somewhat ugly) list comprehension:

```
ComboTuples = [((i[j] for i in SubscriptsArray)...) for j in 1:length(Minima)]
# results in:
#   5-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
#   (4,3,1)
#   (4,3,3)
#   (3,4,3)
#   (4,5,3)
#   (4,3,4)
```

Comment: Works beautifully! I iterated over an array of arrays containing B..N and recursively filled up A with more and more elements. Thanks for your troubles!

Comment: Glad it works :)
Updated with a concise "tl;dr" solution on the top regardless. Hopefully this adds something useful too :)

Comment: Thank you i appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's see if I understand this.  You've got `n` matrices and want all combinations with one column from each of the `n` matrices?  If so, how about the `product()` (for Cartesian product) from the [Iterators](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) package?

```
using Iterators

n = 3
Array_of_Arrays = [rand(3,3) for idx = 1:n] ## arbitrary representation of your set of arrays.
Array_of_ColGroups = Array(Array, length(Array_of_Arrays))

for (idx, MyArray) in enumerate(Array_of_Arrays)
    Array_of_ColGroups[idx] = [MyArray[:,jdx] for jdx in 1:size(MyArray,2)]
end

MyProd = product(Array_of_ColGroups...)
```

This will create an iterator object which you can then loop over to consider the specific combinations of columns.

Comment: @isebarn OK, I think I get it now.  I amended with another shot at it, let me know if that is getting at what you're looking for.